# convert a list of repeated items into a succinct dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the list

```
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
```

I want to convert it into a dictionary that is represented like this

```
{'golden coin':3,'dagger':1,'ruby':1}
```

I then want to join it with an existing dictionary to combine the inventory. Is this possible?

Comment: collections.Counter .... also add the existing dictionary for completeness

Answer (score 2):

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) from the collections module to do this

```
from collections import Counter
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
dic = Counter(dragonLoot)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use comprehension dict syntax as follows :

```
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
res = {el: dragonLoot.count(el) for el in  dragonLoot}
print(res)
```

wich prints :

```
{'gold coin': 3, 'ruby': 1, 'dagger': 1}
```